# how can I access NFSv4 with kerberos auth from within Docker container?

Tags: docker, kerberos, nfs4

Our NFSv4 file-server uses Kerberos authentication managed by Active Directory.

I need to run a batch process inside a Docker container that accesses data held on the file-server.

From within the container, I have tried authenticating with the AD and then mounting the NFS file-system, but I cannot access any files on the system.

From outside the container, I can mount the NFS file-system on the host, but if I attach that to a container as a volume, the container cannot access any files.

What is the correct way to do this ? Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it , is to mount the share on the host and figure out what user can access the share , once you do it on host , then map the user id inside the container so that the same user can access the share from within the container the same way it does on the host.